# How to get node ids with path query in Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have a graph built from the following nodes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Node {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String desc;
    @Relationship(type = "CONNECTED_WITH", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<Node> nodes;
    //getters and setters
}
```

My Spring Data repository contains a Cypher query for the shortest paths between these nodes:

```
@Query("START startNode = node({startId}), endNode = node({endId}) " +
       "MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((startNode)-[*]-(endNode)) " +
       "RETURN paths")
Iterable<Map<String, Iterable<Object>>> findShortestPaths(@Param("startId") long startId, @Param("endId") long endId);
```

Second Iterable returns the actual path as a list of nodes and relationships where each of them is represented as a hash map with properties. For a simple graph like this:

> A -- B -- C

the result path for the `findShortestPaths` method between `A` and `C` contains 5 elements:

```
{desc=DescA}, {}, {desc=DescA}, {}, {desc=DescA}
```

I guess that empty maps represent relationships between nodes and in this case they don't have any property. My problem is that maps, which represent nodes, don't contain the `id` property.

**Question:**
Is it possible to return nodes as corresponding entity objects instead of hash maps? And if not, how can I get the ids of the path nodes in the returned hash maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I ended up with a modified Cypher query that beside path nodes returns also extracted ids as a separate iterable inside the result map.

```
@Query("START startNode = node({startId}), endNode = node({endId}) " +
       "MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((startNode)-[*]-(endNode)) " +
       "RETURN nodes(path) AS nodes, EXTRACT(node IN nodes(path) | ID(node)) AS ids")
```

Although this solution is far from perfect, at least it returns required details.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the node ID's aren't available as part of the Map results. Opened https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-771 to track this.

Comment: Hopefully it'll be taken into consideration. Thank you very much for your effort. Anyway, while waiting for the next release I'm going with a workaround.